# How to add a JavaScript alert message to show that the html form validation is correct using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have the following JavaScript functions which are linked to a HTML file, as they are called by a recordHistory() button in the HTML file. The JavaScript work well functionally, but I will like to include an alert message in the function called recordHistory() to show that once the text fields in the HTML form validation are complete and correct. Once an user can click the onclick Record button in the HTML file, an alert message will appear stating "the text fields are correct and recorded". The JavaScript functions are shown below: -

```
// JavaScript Document
function validateFirstName() { //test input for 2-15 allowed characters
    var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var rel = /^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-]{2,15}$/;
    
    if (rel.test(fName)) { //if input is valid, update page to show successful entry}
        document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").innerHTML = "<strong>valid</strong>"
        return true;
}
    else { //if input is invalid, update page to prompt for new input
            document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").style.color = "Red";
            document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").innerHTML = "<strong>Enter 2&15</strong>"
            return false;
    }   
}

function validateLastName() { //test input for 2-25 allowed characters
    var lName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    var re2 = /^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-']{2,25}$/;
    
    if (re2.test(lName)) { //if input is valid, update page to show successful entry}
        document.getElementById("lastNamePrompt").style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById("lastNamePrompt").innerHTML = "<strong>valid</strong>"
        return true;
}
    else { //if input is invalid, update page to prompt for new input
            document.getElementById("lastNamePrompt").style.color = "Red";
            document.getElementById("lastNamePrompt").innerHTML = "<strong>Enter 2&25</strong>"
            return false;
    }   
}

function recordHistory(){//function to validate input text fields on client side, via record button
var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
var lName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
if( fName ==='' || lName ===''){
alert("Please fill all text fields...!!!!!!");
return false;
}else{
return true;
}   
}
```

the html file has the following button with the recordHistory()function:

```
    <tr>
        <td class="Button" id="Button" colspan="3"><span class="buttonBG" onclick="recordHistory();">Record</span></td>              
   </tr>
```

Basically, I can focus in and out of the html textbox fields and when I click the Record button, an alert box will appear to say that "all input fields of the HTML form have to completed. Once I manually enter the required data in the textbox fields of the HTML form and I click the Record button, no message is displayed (but I know that the validation is complete and correct). My goal is to ensure that once the input fields of the HTML form have been correctly validated, an alert message will display to "All of the data in textbox fields are correct and recorded". I am a newbie here and I was doing some reading and it appears that this is that all JavaScript regular pattern expressions are correctly matched.

I updated the JavaScript function of the RecordHistory() to include some code to match all regular expressions:-

```
function recordHistory(){//function to validate input text fields on client side, via record button
var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
var lName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
if( fName ==='' || lName ===''){
alert("Please fill all text fields...!!!!!!");
return false;
}else{
return true;
if(!(fName).match(fNameReg) || (!(lName).match(lNameReg)){
alert("All text fields are correct and recorded!"");
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
}   
}
```

But this JavaScript code did not work, as a new JavaScript error occurred: - ERROR: Parsing error: Unexpected token{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Subramania Prasad thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
Once each regular expression is validated as correct, a user can click the recordHistory button and an alert will pop-up to say "data input is correct"
I used this code to get the result which I was looking for: -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="#">
    <div id="fullpage">

<tr>
        <td class="Button" id="Button" colspan="3"><span class="buttonBG" onclick="recordHistory();">Record</span></td>              
    </tr>   

    <span id="recordConfirm">&nbsp;</span>
        
</div>
</form>

<script>
function recordHistory(){//function to validate input text fields on client side, via record button
var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
var lName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
var fNameRegExp = /^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-]{2,25}$/;
if( fName ==='' || lName ===''){
alert("Please fill all text fields...!!!!!!");
return false;
}
else if(fName === fNameRegExp){
  //First Name true
}
else{
alert("input data is correct");
return true;
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do see that you are already doing a validation for firstname and lastname using validateFirstName and validateLastName functions.

I believe you would be doing this using either onfocusout for that field.

Doing another validation while clicking the button again might be double work. So I would suggest you to disable the button if FirstName or LastName validation fails on those respective functions themselves.

Add the below line:

```
document.getElementById("somebuttonid").disabled = true;
```

So until those two fields are validated as you like the Button to submit would be disabled. This would also be a better UX than disrupting them with an alert.

Let me know if this would work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I do need to have an alert when the Record button is clicked (I have updated my original Question to show the HTML Record button code and further explanation of what I having to achieve.

Comment: @wire_jp I am also a beginner so I tried this code in jsfiddle without validation.
https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=CBff2FvTDq

This seems to work, one thing I noticed that might be a problem is that in your updated javascript is that
1. the loops are if ,else if and else and not 2 else
2. The second else has return true as the first line so if it matches any of the succeeding statements inside the function won't be executed.

To demonstrate point 2 I have commented return true statement in my jsfiddle , if it is uncommented, it does not trigger the alert.

Comment: @ Subramania Prasad: I ran the code in version 1. in jsfiddle and it seemed to work. With the version 2 code, I tried to modify it to become an if,else ifand else function but I was getting errors.